# Distribute load within chained operators in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an input kinesis stream with a single shard. I create a simple application with a map function but with an environment level parallelism of 8. Using a thread profiler, when I check the threads created, there is only 1 thread that is active for the map function and source(querying, as mentioned in the documentation). I realise that this is because I'm setting the parallelism at an environment level. Is there anyway to distribute the load amongst all the parallel instances created for the map function after it is consumed?

Comment: The single kinesis shard limits the parallelism of the source to 1. After, the map, what does the rest of the pipeline look like?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, after this we have an async operator, a filter, a keyed process function, and a sink.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to put a `rebalance()` right after the kinesis consumer. `rebalance()` does round-trip repartitioning. This will redistribute the events being read from the one shard among the 8 instances of the map that follows it.

[Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#physical-partitioning).

The rebalance will cause ser/de and a network shuffle. You'll have to weigh that against the benefit of having 8 active pipelines rather than one.

Given that your job graph looks something like this,

```
source -> map -> async -> filter -> keyBy + process function -> sink
```

the keyBy later in your pipeline will cause another network shuffle. If you are very concerned about performance, you might be able to get away with doing the keyBy right after the source (instead of using a rebalance there), and then use [reinterpretAsKeyedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/experimental.html#reinterpreting-a-pre-partitioned-data-stream-as-keyed-stream) after the async operator to avoid the second network shuffle. The reason this becomes a bit convoluted is that the async operator doesn't know anything about keyed streams -- and this will only work if the same KeySelector makes sense both before and after the async function.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did go through the documentation but read somewhere that this would have detrimental effects on performance. Would that be a compromise I'd have to make?